# Durandal App. How to deploy to IIS web server?

Tags: durandal

I understand that should be no issue in deploying a Durandal app to IIS. Durandal´s docs says that one should run optimizer.exe , change the reference to main-built.js in main.js and that´s it.
I manually copied the site folder to my web server via ftp. Now, when I type the app´s url in the browser the index.html page is shown as expected but it never shows my welcome view. 
Is this the right way to deploy the app to the web server? Any point I am missing?
TIA

Comment: If using Visual Studio, I would recommend creating an IIS deployment package. As far as *why* it never shows the welcome view - look at the error console and network access. I suspect there is a 404 somewhere, even with an optimized "build". DurandalJS is [unfortunately] overly quite on failed requires but this can be changed by hooking into the RequireJS errors.

Comment: @user2246674, thank you. It was really a 404 on main-built.js. It´s running just fine now.